# Scipy.sparse.csr_matrix slow on matrix with float values

Tags: python, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply two sparse matrices or a sparse matrix with a dense. The size of matrices are roughly 128x256. Their 80% values are 0 and the rest are floating point values with 8 digits of precision roughly.

I am aware of the function scipy.sparse. But I do not want to use this function. Can anyone help with the code in python.

```
WW_sp=numpy.zeros([len(X),Y.shape[1]])
for i in range(len(X)):
A=numpy.where(X[i]!=0)
for j in range(Y.shape[1]):
    B=numpy.where(Y[:,j]!=0)
    for k in numpy.intersect1d(A,B):
        WW_sp[i][j]+=X[i][k]*Y[k][j]
```

This code is good for sparse matrix but takes more time for dense matrix. Can there be any optimized code that works well for both sparse and dense matrix

Comment: Correct the indentation.  Give more specifics about `X` and `Y`.  The subject line suggests you are using `scipy.sparse`, but the text says otherwise.  It looks like you are just doing `X@Y`, matrix multiplication of two 2d arrays.

Comment: Whydo you use `X[i]` and `Y[:,j]` sometimes, and `X[i][k]` others?  Why not `X[i,k]` style of indexing always?  Even if it isn't faster, it is clearer and more idiomatic `numpy`.